# Are vacuum fluctuations that produce dark matter correlated to fluctuations that produce baryonic matter?

Tags: dark-matter, cosmological-inflation, vacuum

When cosmic inflation began vacuum energy fluctuations created matter . But were the fluctuations that created dark matter dependent on the fluctuations that created matter ? Is the ratio of dark matter to baryonic matter random for galaxies for which this has been assessed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This question was only settled in the last decade or so, but initial variations in the baryon density and in the dark matter density seem to agree at the percent level. See for example "[Baryons still trace dark matter: probing CMB lensing maps for hidden isocurvature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03461)".